# How to loop over a tidy eval function using purrr?

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse, purrr, tidyeval

I have the following data set (sample):

```
train <- data.frame(ps_ind_06_bin = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
                        ps_ind_07_bin = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
                        ps_ind_08_bin = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
                        ps_ind_09_log = c(1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2))
```

I have the following function that shows a ggplot for a `group_by()` operation:

```
get_charts1 <- function(mygroup){
  quo_var <- enquo(mygroup)
  train %>% 
    group_by(!!quo_var) %>% 
    count() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
  ggplot(aes_q(x = quo_var, y = quote(n), fill = quo_var)) + 
    geom_col() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
    }
```

It works fine when I manually imput a column name, for example:

```
get_charts1(ps_ind_07_bin)
```

However, I want to use the function on several columns, which I put on a vector:

```
binarias <- train %>% 
             select(ends_with("bin")) %>% 
             colnames()
```

Using map and taking some suggestions, I tried to use:

```
listaplots <- map(quo(!!! syms(binarias)), get_charts1)
```

But this gives me the following error:

> ```
> "Error: Can't splice at top-level"
> ```

Does anyone know what I need to do to get this to work?

Comment: Looks like `map(quos(ps_ind_06_bin , ps_ind_07_bin ), get_charts1)` doesn't work so the problem isn't with expansion really. Seem like `map()` is just forcing evaluation of the parameters.

Comment: Capturing forced objects (including forced quosures or symbols) will work out of the box in the next rlang version. This will be equivalent to unquoting.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 16):

I’m going to start by creating a
[reprex](http://tidyverse.org/help/#reprex) (you were very close, but
forgot to load the needed packages), and re-style to a consistent format
using [styler](http://styler.r-lib.org):

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

train <- data.frame(
  ps_ind_06_bin = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE),
  ps_ind_07_bin = c(FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE),
  ps_ind_08_bin = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE),
  ps_ind_09_log = c(1, 3, 4, 2, 3, 2)
)

get_charts <- function(mygroup) {
  quo_var <- enquo(mygroup)
  train %>%
    group_by(!! quo_var) %>%
    count() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    ggplot(aes_q(x = quo_var, y = quote(n), fill = quo_var)) +
    geom_col() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
}
```

You want to automate the generation of code like this:

```
get_charts(ps_ind_06_bin)
get_charts(ps_ind_07_bin)
get_charts(ps_ind_08_bin)
```

That will require either a for loop or an apply/map function. A `map()`
works well here since we want to return the ggplot2 objects, and doing
that with a for loop requires some more infrastructure. It’s
straightforward once you remember that you need to use symbols here, not
raw strings

```
vars <- train %>% select(ends_with("bin")) %>% colnames()

vars %>%
  syms() %>%
  map(function(var) get_charts(!!var))

## [[1]]
```

[image]

```
## 
## [[2]]
```

[image]

```
## 
## [[3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Rather than `map`, I think you want `invoke_map` here. This seems to give what you want

```
listaplots  <- invoke_map(get_charts1, rlang::syms(binarias))
```

The `map()` seems to force evaluation of the parameters while `invoke_map` does not.

Answer (score 1):

Change `enquo()` to `sym()` and your code works fine like this:

```
get_charts1 <- function(mygroup){
    quo_var <- sym(mygroup)  # <- HERE

    train %>% 
      group_by(!!quo_var) %>% 
      count() %>%
      ungroup() %>%
      ggplot(aes_q(x = quo_var, y = quote(n), fill = quo_var)) + 
      geom_col() +
      theme(legend.position = "none")
}

binarias <- train %>% select(ends_with("bin")) %>% colnames()

binarias %>% map(get_charts1)
```